# Setting to compile with glib, dbus lib in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glib, dbus

I'm making a program with glib and dbus libs.
However I need to guide compile this on Eclipse.

There are errors for these lines..
"Unresolved inclusion"

```
 include <dbus/dbus.h>
 include <glib.h>
```

What kind of options and command needed for Tool Settings(Gcc c++ compiler/gcc c++ linker) on Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Use package config to get the libs and cflags needed

```
pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 dbus-1

pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 dbus-1
```

and put them into according places in the Eclipse UI.

Comment: Not very useful, the question was how to do this in eclipse, so you can not say "just do it in eclipse" that completely ignores the question.

Answer (score 0):

That is a common error on eclipse, it uses the system path, but the system maybe uses a library handler like pkg-config, so normally eclipse displays a lot of missing includes, but the program builds correctly (if you set pkg-config on your makefiles), because is just only eclipse how can't find the headers.
to solve this, add /usr/include/glib-2.0/ to your project include path on eclipse
or install an addon to handle the includes like [Pkg-config support for Eclipse CDT 0.8.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt#.VGN8y1u1CV4) this one